# Running npm install for nuget package

Tags: npm, nuget

I have a package that contains dlls as well as js code along with `package.json` and I want to publish both npm and nuget packages. My project does not have any dependency on any other nuget packages but has dependency on some node modules.

For Npm package all I have to do is npm pack.

For nuget how do I package this such that whenever the package is install the node moduel dependencies are also restored.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is explained in the docs

Comment: I know how to include content files but I couldn't find a way to implicitly run `npm install` after nuget install/restore

Answer (score 0):

You can include an `Init.ps1` file within your NuGet package. Add it in your `.nuspec` file like

```
<files>
    <file src="Init.ps1" target="tools\Init.ps1" />
</files>
```

And the `Init.ps1` file will run as post-install PowerShell script.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package)
npm pack
```